# Xamarin. Load picture from disc and save it to database

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms and want to load an image which is saved in a subfolder of the application. 
**EDIT 1:** the image is saved in runtime, it is taken by the camera.

I want to load the image to be able to save it to a database as byte array.

I am having problems to load the image. I pass the path of the current directory but it says that it does not exists. Code in Android Project:

```
private bool ImageExists()
    {
        var imagePath = "accessEventPhoto.jpg";
        var documentsPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, imgFolder);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, imagePath);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**EDIT 2:** when I debug the code path value is

```
"/ImagesFolder/accessEventPhoto.jpg"
```

I use the camera with this call and set the path to save the photo:

```
public async Task<string> OpenCameraResync()
{
    var picker = new MediaPicker(Forms.Context);
    if (!picker.IsCameraAvailable)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No camera!");
    else
    {
        var intent = picker.GetTakePhotoUI(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Name = "accessEventPhoto.jpg",
            Directory = imgFolder
        });
        var mainActivity = Forms.Context as MainActivity;
        mainActivity.StartActivity(intent, OnActivityResult);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I find the correct path to the image and load it?

Comment: Is the image included as part of your app's distributable, or is it created/saved at runtime?

Comment: When you debug what it shows for `path` and where is the real image?

Comment: @Jason there I updated the post. Thanks

Comment: @EZI there I updated the post. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to load an image you saved to the Android image gallery, or have you saved it to some custom app path?